# Notation: Markov chain with continuous state space

Tags: notation, markov-chains, markov-process

Let $(M_n)_{n\geq0}$ denote a Markov chain with continuous state space and $X$ some $\mathbb{N}$-valued random variable. To my knowledge, the transition probabilities of $M$ are usually described by transition kernels.

*Question 1:* In a paper I read the transition kernels were written as: $P (x; dy)$. Is it correct that the "common" notation for this would be $\kappa (x, dy)$?

*Question 2:* Moreover, is it legitimate to write
\begin{align}
P(X = x, M_n \in dy) = P(X=x \vert M_n = y) P(M_n \in dy),
\end{align}
or is this abuse of notation or simply not correct?

*Remark:* I am aware that sometimes $M$ is not called a Markov chain anymore as its state space is continuous, but don't let it bother you here.